# Add some string to all elements of a large (16Mill) list (might be a question about apply syntax)

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

I'm trying to get something that looks like this:

```
mylist <- list(c("a"), c("a", "b"), c("a","b","c"))
```

into something that looks like this:

```
list(c("y ~ a"), c("y ~ a + b"), c("y ~ a + b + c"))
```

for one element, I can do this:

```
test <- paste0("y ~ ", paste0(mylist[[3]], collapse = " + "))  
test
[1] "y ~ a + b + c"
```

so I thought I'd try to use an apply and that works, too:

```
mylistupdater <- function(X){
mylist[[X]] <- paste0("y ~ ", paste0(mylist[[X]], collapse = " + "))  
}
lapply(c(1:length(mylist)), mylistupdater)
```

the problem is, that my real list has 16 million entries and this is way to slow. I think I'm writing the apply function very badly, like a loop. It should not address an index but rather the list directly, right? But the examples I see online just include a simple function. How can I pass arguments to it with these two `paste0()` commands and with a cleaner `lapply()`? Or is there a `data.table` solution? The output could well be a column in a data.table. Speed is actually important this time.

**edit:**
@akrun and @Rui provide great answers below that solve my problem. I now have the luxury to think about speed and here is a horserace repeating each of the answers 100,000 times on my machine:

the version with `mylistupdater(mylist)`: Time difference of 1.072506 secs

the version with `lapply(mylist, reformulate, response = "y")`: Time difference of 10.5461 secs

the version with `lapply(mylist, function(x) format(reformulate(x, "y")))`: Time difference of 18.20975 secs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `lapply` call do what the question asks for. Then, assign the result back to the regressors list or to a results list.

```
mylistupdater <- function(X, response = "y"){
  lapply(X, function(x) {
    x <- paste(x, collapse = " + ")
    paste(response, x, sep = " ~ ")
  })
}

mylistupdater(mylist)
#[[1]]
#[1] "y ~ a"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "y ~ a + b"
#
#[[3]]
#[1] "y ~ a + b + c"
```

Comment: this is faster than the version @akrun provides. Any idea why?

Comment: @PeterPan Maybe because `reformulate` is a general purpose function, it has to process all sorts of inputs, so it spends time deciding which branch of the code to follow.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `reformulate`

```
lapply(mylist, reformulate, response = "y")
```

If it needs to be a string

```
lapply(mylist, function(x) format(reformulate(x, "y")))
#[[1]]
#[1] "y ~ a"

#[[2]]
#[1] "y ~ a + b"

#[[3]]
#[1] "y ~ a + b + c"
```

Comment: Thanks, fantastic! In case anyone cares in the future: I ran both versions 10,000 times and the first version took 1.180392 secs, the second (string) version took 1.981269 secs. The first one is faster.

Comment: Ok no problem.  I got confused with your previous comment.  The reason could be that `reformulate` does some sanity checks inside and that would make it slower.  But, it is convenient not to includde all the variable names when there is a lot

Comment: Thanks! I pointed out all versions in my original question. And thanks for pointing out reformulate. That looks really useful for the future